# Mobile Menu not disappearing for larger screens

Tags: javascript, responsive

I'm very new to coding and have been following tutorials to learn coding. I have very successfully created a hamburger menu after following a tutorial and I'm totally chuffed!
My happiness soon faded away when I realised that the mobile menu doesn't disappear if I forget to click the X and expand the screen. The Menu remains. I have attached the Code and HTML and CSS. Please can someone help me write the correct code to make it disappear?

I have tried to do this with CSS by adding 'display: none' to the mobile_menu and mobile_menu bottom' ... and also tried moving it with the transitionX(100%) but to no luck.
So I'm guessing this a JS related issue which I have 0 knowledge at the moment.

sadly I can't post images because I don't have 10 reputations. sad. so I'll try and paste it here.

`hamburger`

```
<div> 
<button type="button" class="hamburger" id="menu-btn" > 
<span class="top"></span> 
<span class="middle"></span> 
<span class="bottom"></span> 
</button>
</div>

<div class="mobile-menu hidden" id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">worship and music</a></li>
<li><a href="#">visit us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">support us</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="mobile-menu-bottom">
<button class="btn donate">donate</button>
<a href="#"><img src="images/pin.png" alt="locator">  
<span>locate us</span></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

`CSS Code:`

```
.navbar{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color: #F6F6F4;
padding:20px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%),
    0 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 6%),
    0 0 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%);
}

.navbar-container{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
}

.navbar ul {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.navbar li {
margin: 0 20px;
}


.navbar-brand img{

width: 320px;
height:113px;
margin: auto 0;
margin-left: 25px;

}

.navbar-nav-left{
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: .9rem;
}

.navbar-nav-right img
{
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav-right li:first-child a 
{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
 }



.btn {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
background: none;
border: 1px #000 solid;
border-radius: 50px;
padding: 7px 16px;
line-height: 1.2;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}

.donate {
background-color: var(--Purple);
border: none;
font-size: 1rem;    
}

.donate:hover {
background-color:white;
font-size: 1rem;
color: #000000;}

.donate_button{
color: white;
}

.hamburger {
cursor: pointer;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
position: relative;
background: none;
border: none;
z-index: 10;
transition: all 0.25s;
padding: 0 25px;
display: none;  
}


.top, .middle, .bottom {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 24px;
height: 2px;
background: #000000;
transform: rotate(0);
transition: all 0.5s;
}

.middle {
transform: translateY(7px);
}

.bottom {
transform: translateY(14px);
}

.open .top {
transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(6px) translateX(6px);
}
.open .middle {
opacity: 0;
}

.open .bottom {
transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(6px) translateX(-6px);
}
```

`mobile menu`

```
.mobile-menu {
position: fixed;
background-color:#abc09f;
top: 161px;
right:0;
width: 90%;
height: 100%;
padding: 30px;
box-shadow: inset 0 4px 3px -3px rgb(0 0 0 /10%),
    inset 0 4px 2px -2px rgb(0 0 0 /7%);
transition: all 0.3s;}

.mobile-menu div a {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
font-size:1rem;
}


.hidden {
transform: translateX(100%);
} 

.no-scroll {
overflow: hidden;
}

@media(max-width: 768px){

.hamburger {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-brand img{

width: 220px;
height:113px;
margin: auto 0;
margin-left: 25px;

}

.navbar .navbar-nav-left, 
.navbar .navbar-nav-right{
    display: none;
}
}


@media(max-width:1080px){
.hamburger {
display: block;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav-left, 
.navbar .navbar-nav-right{
    display: none;}
 }
```

`JS SCRIPT`

```
const btn = document.getElementById('menu-btn')
const nav = document.getElementById('menu')


function navToggle() {
btn.classList.toggle('open')
nav.classList.toggle('hidden')
document.body.classList.toggle('no-scroll')
}

btn.addEventListener('click', navToggle)
```

Comment: Please add the Html and CSS code too. It's not possible to answer just by looking at JavaScript.

Comment: Hope that helps. Sorry.. (Newbie here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the mobile menu CSS section. You have to add `translateX(100%)` to mobile-menu to hide the mobile menu on a bigger screen by default.

For the smaller screen change it to `translateX(0%)` so that it shows the menu when the **'hidden'** class is not active.

And move the `.hidden{translateX(100%)}` to the 1080px media query as it is not needed for the bigger screen. The changes are wrapped inside the comments.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('menu-btn')
const nav = document.getElementById('menu')


function navToggle() {
    btn.classList.toggle('open')
    nav.classList.toggle('hidden')
    document.body.classList.toggle('no-scroll')
}

btn.addEventListener('click', navToggle)
```

```css
.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #F6F6F4;
    padding:20px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%),
        0 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 6%),
        0 0 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%);
}
.navbar-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.navbar ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.navbar li {
    margin: 0 20px;
}
.navbar-brand img{
    width: 320px;
    height:113px;
    margin: auto 0;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
.navbar-nav-left{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: .9rem;
}
.navbar-nav-right img{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.navbar-nav-right li:first-child a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    background: none;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 7px 16px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.donate {
    background-color: var(--Purple);
    border: none;
    font-size: 1rem;    
}

.donate:hover {
    background-color:white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #000000;
}
.donate_button{
    color: white;
}
.hamburger {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    z-index: 10;
    transition: all 0.25s;
    padding: 0 25px;
    display: none;  
}
.top, .middle, .bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 24px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000000;
    transform: rotate(0);
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.middle {
    transform: translateY(7px);
}
.bottom {
    transform: translateY(14px);
}
.open .top {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(6px) translateX(6px);
}
.open .middle {
    opacity: 0;
}
.open .bottom {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(6px) translateX(-6px);
}
.mobile-menu {
    position: fixed;
    background-color:#abc09f;
    top: 161px;
    right:0;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px 3px -3px rgb(0 0 0 /10%),                inset 0 4px 2px -2px rgb(0 0 0 /7%);
    transition: all 0.3s;

    /* ------------------Change here---------------*/

    transform: translateX(100%);       /* add translateX(100%) to hide the menu in bigger screen by default  */

    /* ------------------Change here---------------*/
}
.mobile-menu-bottom .nav__img{
    max-width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
.mobile-menu div a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size:1rem;
}
.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
    .hamburger {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-brand img{
        width: 220px;
        height:113px;
        margin: auto 0;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav-left, 
    .navbar .navbar-nav-right{
        display: none;
    }
}
@media(max-width:1080px){
    .hamburger {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav-left, 
    .navbar .navbar-nav-right{
        display: none;
    }
    /* ------------------Change here---------------*/

    .mobile-menu{
        transform: translateX(0%);    /* Here mobile-menu will be shown if hidden class is not active */
    }
    .hidden {
        transform: translateX(100%);   /* And the menu will hide again if the hidden class is active*/
    }

    /* ------------------Change here---------------*/
}
```

```html
<div> 
        <button type="button" class="hamburger" id="menu-btn" aria-label="hamburger"> 
            <span class="top"></span> 
            <span class="middle"></span> 
            <span class="bottom"></span> 
        </button>
    </div>  
    <div class="mobile-menu hidden" id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">worship and music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">visit us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">support us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="mobile-menu-bottom">
            <button class="btn donate">donate</button>
            <a href="#"><img class="nav__img" src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/location-icon-simple-symbol-red-pin-sign_399998-369.jpg?w=2000" alt="locator">  
            <span>locate us</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Rocky, you opened my eyes to what was wrong. I had also needed to add into the correct media query which was min-width 1081px
It disappears now! Thank you so much!

Comment: @denni glad to help. Please mark the answer if it does fix your problem. It makes my soul happy XD.

Comment: Ok .. just did! Hope to see you again in one of my mannnny questions 